# How to convert timestamp to date string?

Tags: javascript

How should I convert timestamp value (2021170519) returned from api to a date string with format HH:SS DD.MM.YY (20:21 17.05.19)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the format is consistent, you can dissect the string into smaller chunks with a regular expression:

```js
var str = '2021170519' 
str = str.match(/.{1,2}/g)

const newStr = `${str[0]}:${str[1]} ${str[2]}.${str[3]}.${str[4]}`

console.log(newStr)
```

I would recommend using a library like moment.js, however.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is **unified** and numbers are **padded** you can just access their indexes.

```js
var data = "2021170519";

var hh = data[0] + data[1];
var mm = data[2] + data[3];

var dd = data[4] + data[5];
var MM = data[6] + data[7];
var yyyy = data[8] + data[9];


console.log(hh + ":" + mm + " " + dd + "." + MM + "." + yyyy);
```

Comment: You have reassigned the variable `mm`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [moment.js library](https://momentjs.com/) and format the date as you wish.

```
moment(timestamp).format('hh:ss dd.MM.YY');
```